# How to determine what causes IE 11 to recreate "Adobe" folder (all Adobe software should be uninstalled)

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, flash

A couple of months ago I went through my (Windows 7) PC and removed all versions (incl. all browser add-ins, etc.) of Adobe Flash from the system. After following the available uninstallation processes I manually deleted any "Adobe" and "Macromedia" folders.

I do not have any other Adobe products such as Acrobat or Illustrator installed on this machine.

Today I noticed that launching IE 11 causes an "Adobe" folder (with a subfolder structure "Flash Player\NativeCache") created in "C:\Users[my username]\AppData\Roaming\".

The folder (and it's subfolders) are created empty, which is maybe as expected if it is some kind of a caching folder.

I am assuming that it is added by some process related to IE because, if I delete the Adobe folder, it is not added back until when I launch IE. As far as my IE add-ons are concerned, they are all as shown in below image; no add-ons from Adobe are installed.

[image: All IE add-ons]

How can I determine what process keeps recreating this Adobe folder?

Comment: Does this happen if IE is started in No-Addons mode? To open IE without loading Add-Ons, press `WinKey` + `R`, type `iexplore -extoff` and press ENTER.

Comment: It looks like adobe flash player did not uninstall completely. Follow this guide to make sure it is gone: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html

Comment: You should quote that article and submit an answer.

Comment: @w32sh, thanks I tried that and it launches IE with the "about:NoAdd-ons" URL and the message "Internet Explorer is currently running without add-ons". Still the folder is also created if it does not exist.

Comment: @JackWhite, thanks for that tip, I will try the uninstaller and see if it resolves this issue.

Comment: @JackWhite, I ran the uninstaller and it did not stop the described behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is hard-coded inside IE's core module ieframe.dll. It creates the `Adobe\Flash Player\NativeCache` directory even in a clean (installed) system without Adobe Flash.

Comment: Thanks @w32sh, would you have a reference to this?

Comment: No reference though. But you can see the hard-coded string using [Strings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/strings.aspx). `strings "C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll" |findstr /i "nativecache"`

Comment: Wow, what a kludge. Looks like w32sh is right